# Как определить текущее значение таймзоны?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Есть функция [`GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-getdynamictimezoneinformation), с помощью которой хочу получить смещение текущего времени от UTC. Да, в структуре, которую она заполняет, есть поля `Bias` и `DaylightBias`, есть даже `DaylightDate`, в которой записано правило перехода на летнее время. Но неужели надо самому разбирать текущую дату и смотреть, сейчас летнее время или нет? Ведь 200% что Windows сама все это вычисляет.

Так как правильно получить текущее смещение от UTC для локальных настроек на компьютере, с учетом летнего времени? И без того чтоб писать свой код сравнения даты с правилом перехода?

Comment: *"Но неужели надо самому разбирать текущую дату и смотреть, сейчас летнее время или нет?"* - так в предложении выше же расписано, как получить из результат вызова `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation` все нужные данные.

Comment: @user7860670 Данные-то есть, но какой смысл писать свой разбор двух дат, если операционная система и так знает, сейчас летнее время или нет? А конкретного флага "сейчас действует летнее время" там нет. И зачем мне писать разбор дат наподобие "а не наступил ли уже третий понедельник апреля?", если это уже реализовано в Windows? Или я что-то не досмотрел, и там есть такой флаг?

Comment: ¿С чего вам так приспичило писать разбор дат? ¿Чем не устраивает текущее значение таймзоны и/или летнего времени, возвращаемое `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`? Вообще показали бы код, что вы там делаете, а то совершенно непонятно.

Comment: @user7860670 Стыжусь. Не увидел. Привык, что в Windows возвращаемое значение всегда успешно-неуспешно. Напишите как ответ, чтоб я принял.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, если надо *вот прямо сейчас*, то как вариант - сравнить время локальное и время UTC, только перевести в `FILETIME`. Ну, и сделать определенные телодвижения для выяснения знака. Может, можно и проще и надежнее, но в качестве первого приближения...

Значение в секундах. +10000 при пересчете (0.1ms) - чтоб точно убрать возможную разность между моментами определения локального и UTC времени. Может, и не требуется, но мало ли :)

```
int tzOffs() // In s
{
    SYSTEMTIME     st,  lt;
    FILETIME       sft, lft;
    ULARGE_INTEGER sli, lli;
    
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    GetLocalTime(&lt);

    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st,&sft);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&lt,&lft);

    sli.LowPart  = sft.dwLowDateTime;
    sli.HighPart = sft.dwHighDateTime;

    lli.LowPart  = lft.dwLowDateTime;
    lli.HighPart = lft.dwHighDateTime;

    int offs = (lli.QuadPart > sli.QuadPart) ?
        (lli.QuadPart - sli.QuadPart + 10000)/10000000 :
        (sli.QuadPart - lli.QuadPart + 10000)/10000000;
    if (lli.QuadPart < sli.QuadPart) offs = -offs;

    return offs;
}
```

Comment: ¿К чему эти костыли, когда вся нужная информация возвращается при вызове `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`?

Comment: @user7860670 ТС пишет, что не работает. Кстати, думаю, что ему к ней нужна функция, отвечающая, сегодня летнее время или нет? Опять же кстати, я такую не искал, так что напишите свой ответ...

Comment: Не вижу чтобы он писал, что у него что-то не работало. Там даже непонятно, пробовал он что-то реально или просто не разобрался до конца с этой функцией.

Comment: Спасибо, но пока не принимаю - неужели нет способа проще? Кстати, вы правы, именно это - сейчас летнее время или нет - я и хочу выяснить. Нет такой функции в API?

Comment: @Mikhailo *"именно это - сейчас летнее время или нет - я и хочу выяснить"* А почему тогда в заголовке совсем другой вопрос?