# Определить часовой пояс стандартной библиотекой time.h

Tags: c

возникла необходимость определения и вывода часового пояса, поискал в интернете и не нашел как сделать это стандартными методами не используя консоль, так вообще можно сделать? Или обязательно нужно обращаться в консоль?

Comment: В разных операционных системах разная реализация часовых поясов, так что универсального решения существовать не может. Наверное, лучшее что можно сделать - получить текущее смещение путём вычитания gmtime из localtime или типа того (однако важно понимать, что смещение это не часовой пояс)

Comment: @andreymal хорошая идея, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: А при чем тут "не используя консоль"? Это что-то из серии "как включить телевизор, не заходя в парикмахерскую"... Кстати, если под Windows — то гляньте на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1489631/195342

Comment: @Harry программа написана как для линукса так и для window, не хотел использовать системные вызовы, может не правильно выразился с консолью.